# c - warning: pointer argument of a function may be used uninitialized

Tags: c

```
     #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

void multiplyMatrix (int **first, int **second, int **multiply);
int m, n, p, q, i, c, d, k, sum = 0;
int main()
{
  int **first, **second, **multiply;

  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
  first = (int **) malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

        first[i]=(int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
  }
  printf("Enter the elements of first matrix\n");

  for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
      scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);

  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);
  second = (int **) malloc(p * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < q ; i++){

        second[i]=(int *) malloc(p * sizeof(int *));
  }
  if (n != p)
    printf("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.\n");
  else
  {
    printf("Enter the elements of second matrix\n");

    for (c = 0; c < p; c++)
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);

    /*for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++) {
        for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
          sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
        }

        multiply[c][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }*/
    multiplyMatrix(first, second, multiply);
    printf("Product of entered matrices:-\n");

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        printf("%d\t", multiply[c][d]);

      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

void multiplyMatrix (int **first, int **second, int **multiply)
{

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++) {
        for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
          sum = sum + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
        }

        multiply[c][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

The program i want to write should be like this: The program asks to the user to enter both the sizes and elements of 2 matrices (or you can call it 2d arrays). Then it will multiply those matrices and print the answer.

The problem i am getting: i used pointers and malloc functions to dynamically allocate the matrices. for the multiplication, i created a function called "multiplyMatrix" which i get a warning for one of the arguments of it in the decleration. here is the warning:

*warning: 'multiply' may be used uninitialized in this function.*

so there is some kind of a problem with initializing this argument. i feel like the answer is simple but at the same time i can't find the solution.

Comment: sizeof (int) != sizeof (int*)

Comment: You have not allocated the memory to be used by multiply.

Comment: Also pointers are passed by value to functions.   Passing an uninitialised pointer to a function gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Compiler is telling you that in `main` you are using the `multiply` variable without initialising it. Did you mean to `malloc` memory for `multiply` before passing it to the `multiplyMatrix` invocation?

Comment: You can't dynamically allocate compact 2D arrays in C. You have to use array-of-pointer, and you have to allocate the intermediate pointer arrays.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc (and family of functions)  the type is already `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer. Also, such casting creates opportunities for coding errors and is a real headache when performing maintenance on the code.  All that casting accomplishes is to clutter the code, making it less understandable.    The returned value from malloc (and family of functions) should always be checked (!=NULL) before usage to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Why that? `int (*p)[OUTER][INNER] = malloc(sizeof(*p));`?

Comment: `int **` is **not** an array/a matrix!

Comment: thanks for all of the comments. all of you helped me a lot and i finally did it. it was actually really simple but its 3 am in the morning here and i am really tired. thank you again and have a good day.

Comment: Olaf, to access a *compact* 2D array with C, you have to know the inner dimension at compile time--you can't dynamically set both dimensions. An array-of-pointer style 2D array doesn't have that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated the memory to be used by the multiply matrix - hence it is being flagged as uninitialised.

You also need to review how you use your row and column values when allocating the first and second matrices, for example:

```
  first = (int **) malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){

        first[i]=(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
  }
```

(Incorporates comment made by wildplasser)

This will allow first to be accessed as first[row][col]

Comment: i thank both of you to giving me this answer and tips. they helped me a lot and saved my time. have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `multiply` was declared in main(), however it is never set to point to anything.  it needs to be created the same way as `first` and `second`, however it does not need to have its' values filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to improve your code:

1. Create a function to allocate memory for a matrix.
2. Create a function to read matrix data.
3. Create a function to deallocate memory of a matrix.
4. Avoid use of global variables. Pass the necessary arguments to a function.
5. Use those functions instead of duplicating code in `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** createMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
   int i;
   int** mat = malloc(sizeof(*mat)*rows);
   for ( i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
      mat[i] = malloc(sizeof(*mat[i])*cols);

   return mat;
}

void readMatrix(int** mat, int rows, int cols)
{
   int r;
   int c;
   for ( r = 0; r < rows; ++r )
      for ( c = 0; c < cols; ++c )
         scanf("%d", &mat[c][c]);
}

void deleteMatrix(int** mat, int rows)
{
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
      free(mat[i]);
   free(mat);
}

void multiplyMatrix (int **first, int **second, int **multiply,
                     int frows, int fcols, int scols)
{
   int sum = 0;
   int r;
   int c;
   int k;

   for (r = 0; r < frows; r++) {
      for (c = 0; c < scols; c++) {
         sum = 0;
         for (k = 0; k < fcols; k++) {
            sum += first[r][k]*second[k][c];
         }

         multiply[r][c] = sum;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   int m, n, p, q;
   int r, c;
   int **first, **second, **multiply;

   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

   first = createMatrix(m, n);

   printf("Enter the elements of first matrix\n");
   readMatrix(first, m, n);


   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of second matrix\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);

   if (n != p)
      printf("Matrices with entered orders can't be multiplied with each other.\n");
   else
   {
      second = createMatrix(p, q);

      printf("Enter the elements of second matrix\n");
      readMatrix(second, p, q);

      multiply = createMatrix(m, q);

      multiplyMatrix(first, second, multiply, m, n, q);
      printf("Product of entered matrices:-\n");

      for (r = 0; r < m; r++) {
         for (c = 0; c < q; c++)
            printf("%d\t", multiply[r][c]);

         printf("\n");
      }

      deleteMatrix(multiply, m);
      deleteMatrix(second, p);
   }

   deleteMatrix(first, m);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. i will try to make my program and use those tips in the future.